# Angular localhost development server is not recompiling when using project in a network drive

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, liveserver

My Angular project has been cloned into a **network drive** and using VS code for the development. The project is compiling without any issues and localhost:4200 is launching into the browser.
But when I'm doing any edit and save on any application files, the live server is not recompiling and reloading the browser. Even a browser hard refresh also not giving the updated changes. The changes will be visible only if we redo the compilation using **"ng-serve"** or **"npm-start"** command.

This issue is only noted in network drive. When I use my **local drive** to run this project, the recompilation and browser reloading is working fine smoothly.

**How to solve this issue for the network drive?** any help would be appreciated.